# Do we need an "information" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed today that we have an [information](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information) tag. It seems like it started out benignly, and it has been used for questions about getting system info from the phone or where your personal information is stored. However, I noticed it because [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11348/can-i-access-system-calls) was tagged with [information](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information), seemingly because they were looking for information about a specific topic.

I personally think it's kind of a vague tag, and would be prone to further misuse (like above). My initial thought was to possibly create instead a [system-info](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-info) tag and a [personal-info](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-info) tag (or similar) since I think they would be much less likely to be used in unintended ways. We already have a [user-information](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-information) tag, in fact.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's vague and a meta-tag. I'll see if I can clean up some of those.

*Update*: Okay, I've cleaned the 5 that just had "information". Most of them were changed to [system-info](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-info) so that's probably a good synonym.

Comment: Sounds like a good synonym to me!